# Get specific list of dict from json content using Ansible

Tags: json, list, ansible

I spend a lot of times to finally didn't get what I need, my request is so complicated then I prefer share with you my concern::

I have this json.content to pars it:

```
        "json": {
            "content": [
                {
                    "name": "machine1",
                    "hasChildren": false,
                    "resourceData": {
                        "entries": [
                            {
                                "value": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "value": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)"
                                },
                                "key": "MachineGuestOperatingSystem"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "value": "Folder1"
                                },
                                "key": "VMware.VirtualCenter.Folder"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": {
                                    "type": "boolean",
                                    "value": true
                                },
                                "key": "Destroy"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {

                    "name": "machine2",
                    "hasChildren": false,
                    "resourceData": {
                        "entries": [
                            {
                                "value": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "value": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)"
                                },
                                "key": "MachineGuestOperatingSystem"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "value": "Folder2"
                                },
                                "key": "VMware.VirtualCenter.Folder"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": {
                                    "type": "boolean",
                                    "value": false
                                },
                                "key": "Destroy"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "machine3",
                    "hasChildren": false,
                    "resourceData": {
                        "entries": [
                            {
                                "value": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "value": "Windows Server 2016 or later (64-bit)"
                                },
                                "key": "MachineGuestOperatingSystem"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "value": "Folder3"
                                },
                                "key": "VMware.VirtualCenter.Folder"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": {
                                    "type": "boolean",
                                    "value": true
                                },
                                "key": "Destroy"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

and I'd like to have as output Something like:

```
[{"name":"machine1", "OsName": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)", "Folder": "Folder1"}, {"name":"machine2", "OsName": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)", "Folder": "Folder2"},
{"name":"machine3", "OsName": "Windows Server 2016 or later (64-bit)", "Folder": "Folder3"}]
```

I tried all the solutions but no way, all result not what I want to expect. someone can help me  to find a  solution to get this attended result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _list: "{{ json.content|json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[].{name: name,
                    OsName: resourceData.entries[0].value.value,
                    Folder: resourceData.entries[1].value.value}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _list:
  - Folder: Folder1
    OsName: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)
    name: machine1
  - Folder: Folder2
    OsName: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)
    name: machine2
  - Folder: Folder3
    OsName: Windows Server 2016 or later (64-bit)
    name: machine
```

---

Q: *"**It changes the order of (key, value), so referencing by [0] or [1] will be not the same.**"*

A: Select the items by the keys. You'll have to [pipe](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#pipe-expressions) the results and select the first items of the selected lists, e.g. the task below gives the same results

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _list: "{{ json.content|json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[].{name: name,
                    OsName: resourceData.entries[?key==`MachineGuestOperatingSystem`].value.value|[0],
                    Folder: resourceData.entries[?key==`VMware.VirtualCenter.Folder`].value.value|[0]}"
```

---

Q: *"**Filter 'Red Hat ...' Get output**"*

```yaml
  - Folder: Folder1
    OsName: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)
    name: machine1
  - Folder: Folder2
    OsName: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)
    name: machine2
```

A: Use *selectattr*, e.g. the task below does the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _list|
                 selectattr('OsName', 'eq', 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)')|
                 list }}"
```

---

Q: *"**Where I can learn this kind of search?**"*

A: There are examples in [JMESPath Specification](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#jmespath-specification). As a hint, see the code below on how to translate these examples into Ansible [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries)

[Example1](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#examples)

```yaml
    - name: 'search(foo, {"foo": "value"}) -> "value"'
      debug:
        msg: "{{ _dict|json_query(_query) }}"
      vars:
        _dict: {"foo": "value"}
        _query: "foo"
```

[Example2](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#id9)

```yaml
    - name: 'search(foo[?bar==`10`], {"foo": [{"bar": 1}, {"bar": 10}]}) -> [{"bar": 10}]'
      debug:
        msg: "{{ _dict|json_query(_query) }}"
      vars:
        _dict: {"foo": [{"bar": 1}, {"bar": 10}]}
        _query: "foo[?bar==`10`]"
```

[Example3](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#id13)

```yaml
    - name: 'search(foo | bar, {"foo": {"bar": "baz"}}) -> "baz"'
      debug:
        msg: "{{ _dict|json_query(_query) }}"
      vars:
        _dict: {"foo": {"bar": "baz"}}
        _query: "foo | bar"
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response, , you give me a hope, but in entries has a Thousands of entries and somehow it change the order of (key, value) , so referencing by [0] or [1] will be not the same a each run of playbook.

Comment: You're welcome. Select the items by the keys. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I've tested , it works perfectly, many thanks.

Comment: if you can get me a source of where I can learn this kind of search,I'll be fully appreciated, juste a link can be useful to me to learn how can do so compecated search trough json using ansible

Comment: I've added some examples. In addition to this, take a look at my project [Ansible examples](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples). Search json_query (Examples 2,20,43,69,140,267, ...).

Comment: It remains one thing to acheive what I want to output, how can I filter by resourceData.entries.value.value|[0] ==  "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)"
the idea is to get in output:
```
[{"name":"machine1", "OsName": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)", "Folder": "Folder1"}, {"name":"machine2", "OsName": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)", "Folder": "Folder2"}]
```
I know I ask mutch, but I tried hardly to get what I need , the solution that you gave me above solve the problem but it  just need to check value of os must be only redhat

Comment: I've updated the answer. This is my last comment here. If you have other issues open a new question.